# Can I use IIFE around useEffect hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, iife

I'm working on a project with lots of anti-patterns, and what I saw is IIFE around multiple useEffects, here is what I have:

```
condition &&
      (() => {
        useEffect(() => {
          const calOffsetTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            calcOffsetWidth();
          }, 150);
          return () => {
            clearTimeout(calOffsetTimeout);
          };
        }, [menuWidth.isExpanded, pdfWrapperRef.current]);

        useEffect(() => {
          calcOffsetWidth();
        }, [pdfWrapperRef, desiredScale, zooming]);

        useEffect(() => {
          calcOffsetWidth();
          return () => pdf && pdf.destroy();
        }, [pdf]);

        useEffect(() => {
          window.addEventListener('resize', calcOffsetWidth);

          return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', calcOffsetWidth);
          };
        }, []);
      })();
```

It's working, but the downside is that I can't debug a single thing inside this iife function. I would like to know how bad or good it is to wrap logic (especially hooks) into iife. What i've tried is to add condition inside the deps arrays, but there is too much logic in the project and everything stops working, so it is not the right decision.

Comment: Why not simply move the condition inside the effects?

Comment: @RameshReddy, I've mentioned this in my question, that it breaks the logic which was written before I was applied to this project

Comment: No, hooks must be called at the top level of the component. Not conditionally, not in nested functions, or loops. Remove the conditional and IIFE so the effect hooks are in the component body. You may need to move the conditional inside the hook callbacks and add as dependency for the ones that need it, though it's hard to tell with a name like `condition`.

Comment: Hooks should be called unconditionally and at the [top-level](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level) of the functional component. I am surprised that this code works.

Comment: @Yousaf, I'm surprised as well and dunno how to fix it

Comment: It must be the case then that `condition` is always truthy and the hooks are called each and every render cycle and the linter somehow doesn't pick up on the IIFE. ‍♂️

Comment: @DrewReese The linter uses the function name as a clue, anything that is named `useXXX` triggers the linter rules for hooks. Sometimes this results in false positives if you happen to have some utility function that starts with `use`. But it also means the linter remains silent if your custom hooks have weird names like `myCustomHook` or if it is an anonymous function as is the case here.

Comment: @DrewReese Actually, calling a hook from an IIFE would work just fine - it's just a bit pointless. But yeah, the conditional is the big problem.

Comment: @Martin I understand generally how the react-hooks linting rules work, I was referring to the fact that the usage to ****not*** be flagged within the IIFE. Your answer below sounds very plausible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I try to answer this a thoroughly as I can, bear with me.

Technically you can use an IIFE around any hook calls. So from a *correctness* point of view the IIFE does not pose an issue, but the `condition` infront of it does. Here is the reason for this: All the original React hooks `useEffect`, `useState`, `useRef`, etc. are wired internally to some React book-keeping that absolutely depends on the number and order of hook calls that happen during one specific render function execution; guess how React can differentiate between your `foo` state and your `bar` state in `const [foo] = useState(); const [bar] = useState();`? Easy: the state for both hook calls are kept in an array; the first call gets the first slot, the second call gets the second slot, and so forth. So when your condition changes during runtime from true to false and you happen to have other `useEffect` calls after your conditionally guarded expression those will be associate with slots that were originally created for `useEffect` inside the expression. Mayhem.
So what with custom hooks? Well, in the end they are build upon original React hooks, so the same rules apply.

So why is an IIFE possible? Technically your IIFE is just an anonymous custom hook. What is a custom hook: You can define a function that internally uses hooks, and use your new function as you would use any original React hook. By convention hooks are named `useXXX` but that is only an convention and you could create a hook as an anonymous function if you wanted.

Is it bad practise to do so? Yes. It is confusing and does not bring anything useful to the table. If you want to separate some hook calls, then just make it a custom hook, give it a meaningful name, you can make use of input arguments and return values as you like.